# Height issue in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, height, android-relativelayout, spacing

I'm experiencing a weird problem in a RelativeLayout in Android. How can I set the TextView height to the middle of those ImageViews? I already tried things like centerHorizontal=true but it didn't work!

Thanks for helping me out![image]

```
   <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_small">

   <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/likeButton"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/npl_title"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/likeCounts"
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/likeButton"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/likeButton"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:includeFontPadding="false"
       android:text="50 likes"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/commentButton"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/likeCounts"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/likeCounts"
        android:contentDescription="@string/npl_title"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/commentCounts"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:includeFontPadding="false"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/commentButton"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/commentButton"
       android:text="50 comments"/>
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/npl_title"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/commentCounts"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/commentCounts"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make height of `TextView` to `wrap_content` and then set `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to the `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an align_baseline to the textview and align it with the imageView

```
  <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/likeButton"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_like"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/npl_title"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/likeCounts"
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/likeButton"
       android:layout_toEndOf="@id/likeButton"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/likeButton"
       android:text="50 likes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

use layout_gravity = "center" for completely center location. Btw which textview are you talking about, from the image?